# Setting and using a local variable in build.gradle

Tags: android, gradle

I have some scripts in my build.gradle that pulls from an artifactory repo and copies stuff into the build directory (and other things). I often change the repo so I would like to parameterize the repo like this...

```
jFrogRepo=tokens-purplizer-android

task getTokensFromArtifactory(type: NpmTask) {
    args = ['install', '--save @myCompany/${jFrogRepo}@latest;']
}

task copyColors(type: Copy, dependsOn: 'getTokensFromArtifactory') {
    from("${rootDir}/node_modules/@myCompany/${jFrogRepo}/dist")
    into("${projectDir}/src/main/java/com/myCompany/src/theme")
    include("*.kt")
}
```

That doesnt work. What is the syntax for setting and using a local variable in build.gradle? I dont want to use settings.gradle if possible becuase I'd rather keep the variable with the code it affects. Is it possible to do it all in the same build.gradle file?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you define the variable in your Gradle build script:

```
def jFrogRepo="tokens-purplizer-android"
```

More on this at https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/writing_build_scripts.html#sec:local_variables